# How to overlay an image with a 10x10 grid in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, grid, overlay, pixel

I have a folder with 44 images and I want to overlay each image with a `10x10` grid. The image resolution is `1280x720`.
Does anyone know how to do this? I am rather new in Matlab, but would like to use that program.

Answer (score 3):

The function `plot` is able to plot multiple line at once if you provide a 2D matrix as argument. So you can plot your image and then plot each line of your grid above your image.:

```
% Load your image
I = imread("peppers.png");
% Get image size
s = size(I);
% Choose your grid size
n = 10;
% Construct the line's coordinates of your grid
%              vertical line            horizontal line   
%                    ↑                          ↑           
x = [repmat(linspace(0,s(2),n),2,1)   repmat([0,s(2)].',1,n)];
y = [repmat([0,s(1)].',1,n)   repmat(linspace(0,s(1),n),2,1)];

% Plot the image and the grid.
imshow(I)
hold on
plot(x,y,'g')
```

And we obtain:

[image]

Each line is composed by 4 values: `[x_start x_end y_start y_end]`